# Generating random numbers in PL SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to generate 50 random numbers in the range from 1 to 300.000.000 using PL/SQL (Oracle sql dev)

I tried using
`floor(dbms_random.value(1, 300000000));`

This works, but when I output the numbers, they don't have a good distribution (ex. i need them to be numbers of different digits like: 45, 2, 829, 2000000 etc). Instead, more than 95% of them, have the same number of digits (8 in this case and rarely 7) which is not what I want.
Is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Are you sure it's mostly 8 digits and not 9?

Comment: The behaviour is clear because there are much more numbers with 8 digits than with 1 or 2. Why do you want to use this single function for all these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

> Instead, more than 95% of them, have the same number of digits (8 in this case and rarely 7)

Let's think about that for a moment. Let's look at the distribution of digits in the 1 to 300.000.000 range.

- 9: 200.000.000 (100.000.000 to 300.000.000)
- 8: ~90.000.000  (10.000.000 to 99.999.999)
- 7: ~9.000.000 (1.000.000 to 9.999.999)
- 6: ~900.000 (100.000 to 999.999)
- 5: ~90.000 (10.000 to 99.999)

And so on. Or another way...

- 9: 66% (2 out of 3)
- 8: 30% (9 out of 30)
- 7: 3% (9 out of 300)
- 6: .3% (9 out of 3000)
- 5: .03 % (9 out of 30000)

A good distribution of random numbers will have 96% with 9 or 8 digits. If you got an even distribution of digits, that would be a bad distribution.

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/AMjEjTOc)

Comment: There was already a discussion about that here: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4504790/dbms-random-value-data-distribution

Answer (score 0):

Another approach I can think of is to use the same function with different ranges like -

```
floor(dbms_random.value(1, 10));
floor(dbms_random.value(11, 100));
floor(dbms_random.value(101, 1000));
floor(dbms_random.value(1000, 100000));
floor(dbms_random.value(100001, 300000000));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a more even distribution of lengths then you can use a logarithmic scale and generate a random number between 0 and log<sub>10</sub>300000000 and then raise 10 to that power:

```sql
SELECT FLOOR(POWER(10, DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, LOG(10, 300000000)))) AS random_value
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 20
```

May output:

| RANDOM_VALUE |
| --- |
| 8 |
| 16974213 |
| 310 |
| 7 |
| 24360 |
| 57 |
| 175411274 |
| 107512402 |
| 3832107 |
| 28521 |
| 3 |
| 43978239 |
| 153212 |
| 907350 |
| 273253102 |
| 1 |
| 13877946 |
| 27677 |
| 1 |
| 1267448 |

*Note: With a logarithmic scale,  there will be the same chance to get the numbers 1-10 as it is to get the value 11-100 or 1001-10000 or 10001-100000, etc. So 7 will be 10 times more likely to occur than 70 and 100 times more likely to occur than 700.*

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/eRm1yqZ-)